# Make the width of outer div to fit inner divs automatically

Tags: html, css

I have 2 inner divs inside an outer div, and I want to make the outer div to automatically fit to the width of the inner divs. Is that possible?

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
}
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>text1</div>
  <div class='inner'>text2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good question frosty :+1 Useful to know when creating a progress bar

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `outer` div is a *block-level element*. You need to make it an *inline-level element*. `Inline` elements automatically take the size of the content it contains. In terms of the question you've asked, just setting :

```
display: inline-block
```

on your outer div will do the trick. See the code snippet below for the demo :

```css
  body {
      font-size: 0;
    }
    #outer {
      border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .inner {
      font-size: 12px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div id='outer'>

  <div class='inner'>
    text1
  </div>
  <div class='inner'>
    text2
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: but when there isn't enough space, and the inner divs wrap on two lines, then the outer div is larger than the inner div. How can this be changed?

Comment: that helped Satwick :+1

Answer (score 4):

Add "display: table;" to the #outer css:

For example:

```
#outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
}
```

using display: table is less intrusive as using inline

Comment: After 5 years this is the best answer, I was trying to fix some absolute positioned tooltips inside td elements of a table, but they didn't expand over the td width. Now are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position:absolute;` or `float:left;` to `#outer` it will size to the two inner `div`'s. For this instance, I would use the `float`. `Floats` are generally better for content that might change or expand/shrink with edits over time whereas `absolute positioning` should be used outside of the document flow or structure of the document, like a nav bar.

Edit: If you don't need other elements to flow around the outer `div` the `display:inline-block` method posted below will work, but if you have elements you want to flow around `#outer` then `float:left` would be the way to go. Say you have `#outer` as 50% of the width and want something else on the other half of the page using `display:inline-block` will put other elements below `#outer`.

[CodePen link to show difference](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwrLeV)