# Stretching a wrapper to full width of its content

Tags: html, css

I want to consistently stretch a `background-color` of a wrapper behind its content. The problem is, that when the content overflows its wrappers, the background wrapper doesn't get adjusted to that.

```html
<div style="background-color: black;min-height: 10px;">
  <div style="width: 100px;">
    <div style="background-color: red;min-height: 5px;min-width: 10000px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that the black background only covers the viewports width, not the used page width. Is there a way to "fix" this behavior? I already tried using `display: inline-block;` but besides the fact, that this would be semantically wrong, is doesn't solve my problem. I also already tried using `display: table`, but it doesn't work either, because of the fixed width middle layer.

Notice that the inner wrapper is isolated in its own file and it wouldn't be possible for the outer wrapper to overwrite `display` for each childrens children of the inner wrapper.

I'm using `width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0` as my viewport meta content.

Comment: so you want your contents overlap its parent wrapper, right?

Comment: When there is a way to adjust the width of the wrapper (so the overlapping "vanishes"), then I'm open to this solution.

Comment: Do you want to hide the contents that overlaps the wrapper?

Comment: `display:inline-block; min-width:100%` for the outer container …?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make the width of outer div to fit inner divs automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026202/make-the-width-of-outer-div-to-fit-inner-divs-automatically)

Comment: It isn't solvable by using `display: inline-block`, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

**it can be solved using just 1 css property and will work in every browser:**

```
display:table
```

you can apply to the any n number of parent.

```html
<div style="background-color: black;min-height: 10px;display:table">
  <div style="width: 100px;display:table">
    <div style="background-color: red;min-height: 5px;min-width: 10000px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, that when I fix the width of my middle div, this solution won't work anymore, too. I've edited my question, with the new information. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, but I haven't had that information before, too. :/

Comment: @Ole Bläsing just solved your second question here, display table to that div also

Comment: Hm, that would work, but it wouldn't be a flexible solution, because of the `display` rule enforcement. However, I upvoted your answer, because it solves the original example. I'm sorry, that it doesn't work completely work out for my problem.

Comment: okay, what do you mean by "display rule enforcement", lets solve it , I have plenty of time for this kinda questions!

Comment: The outer wrapper is defined in an isolated file and just includes plenty of files of the inner wrappers kind dynamically. I would have to ensure that every inner wrapper uses the `display` rule, which would be painful for other developers, if they want to extend given or create new "inner wrapper files".

Comment: _“I would have to ensure that every inner wrapper uses the display rule, which would be painful for other developers”_ - why, you are not really using _inline_ styles all over the place, right …?

Comment: Nope, but if I think about a structure, where the "overflowing" element is deeply nested and far away from our outer wrapper, I would have to set `display: table` to every element between the two. That wouldn't be practicable and even impossible if I have to use something different than `table` (which I must).